# Is it possible to not overrule a global variable in the scope of a function, when it has the same name?

Tags: javascript

```
const a = 3;

function b(a) {
  console.log(a);
  console.log(window.a); // undefined
} 

b(4);
```

Is there a way to have the same naming `a` for global and local variable and still distinguish between them?

Comment: That `const a` is not "a global". It's just a regular scoped variable. And you didn't define it on "window" so you're not going to find it there later. Then again, amusingly, neither are `window.a` or `globalThis.a` global variables: now that `a` is just an object property on a special DOM object, or a special JS language object, respectively. So: what are you _really_ trying to do where this becomes important? =)

Comment: What do you mean with `a` is just an object property on a special DOM object? For example when I run this code in the developer console. What is the special DOM object? interesting, thank you

Comment: `window` is not part of the JavaScript language itself, it's a special object that you get if you're working in something that implements the JS portions of the DOM specification (so, all browsers, but not Node.js for example). If you use the dev console, you'll notice that `let a = 4; window.a` will tell you that `window.a` is undefined because you didn't declare a property `a` on the `window` object, you declared a variable `a` in the dev console's execution scope.

Answer (score 0):

No, there’s no way to directly access an arbitrary shadowed variable in JavaScript.

You should name the parameter something non-conflicting to avoid shadowing the variable in the outer scope.